# How do I SUM total between date and status

Tags: php, mysql

Current db structure `payment`

```
ID pending  paid    begin_work  end_work    status
----------------------------------------------------
1  100      20      2011-08-01  2011-08-30  pending 
2  200      1000    2011-08-01  2011-08-15  pending 
3  500      100     2011-08-05  2011-08-25  pending
4  0        200     2011-07-1   2011-08-25  paid
```

How do I sum pending & paid payment between current month & status?

```
$qm = $db->query("
   SELECT
   begin_work, end_work, status,  
   SUM(pending) AS mpending, 
   SUM(paid) AS mpaid
     FROM payment
    ")
```

Results for `August 2011` should be

```
 pending = 800
 paid    = 1320
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT begin_work, end_work, status, SUM(pending), SUM(paid)
FROM payment
GROUP BY YEAR(begin_work), MONTH(begin_work)
```

Comment: I got `[begin_work] => 0000-00-00 [begin_work] => 0000-00-00`

Comment: That kind of date value means you've inserted invalid dates into the table. MySQL expects/requires date/time values to be in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`-type format.

Comment: sorry.. had 0000-00-00 value in my db.. now worked :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `begin`, `end` and `status` and you're there.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   begin_work, status,  
   SUM(pending) AS mpending, 
   SUM(paid) AS mpaid
FROM payment
where MONTHNAME(begin_work) = MONTHNAME(CURDATE())
group by status
```